# Slow php script

Tags: php, mysql, function, select

I really dislike Full-Text just because I havent got it to work for me so I decided to use a long match against. I was wondering if there's a way to improve this code in speed. I understand its bulky and that 99% of it is crap . But all I really wanted out of it is something that can look through my whole table and sort this by relevance.:

```
if (isset($_GET['post_title'])) {
  $colname_getPosts = $_GET['post_title'];
}
mysql_select_db($database_Main);
function test($string){
    $output = '';
$array = explode(' ', $string);
foreach ($array as $arraytags) {$output .= ' OR MATCH(post_title, post_entry, post_author, tags)
AGAINST("%'.$arraytags.'"IN BOOLEAN MODE)'; } 
$array = explode(' ', $string);
foreach ($array as $arraytags) {$output .= ' OR MATCH(post_title, post_entry, post_author, tags)
AGAINST("%'.$arraytags.'%"IN BOOLEAN MODE)'; } 
$array = explode(' ', $string);
foreach ($array as $arraytags) {$output .= ' OR MATCH(post_title, post_entry, post_author, tags)
AGAINST("'.$arraytags.'%"IN BOOLEAN MODE)'; } 
$array = explode(' ', $string);
foreach ($array as $arraytags) {$output .= ' OR MATCH(post_title, post_entry, post_author, tags)
AGAINST("'.$arraytags.'"IN BOOLEAN MODE)'; } 
return $output;
}
$query_getPosts = "
SELECT post_id, post_date, post_title, post_author, post_entry, tags, sum(relevance)
FROM (
SELECT post_id, post_date, post_title, post_author, post_entry, tags, 10 AS relevance FROM blog_posts WHERE MATCH(post_title) AGAINST('%$colname_getPosts%' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
UNION
SELECT post_id, post_date, post_title, post_author, post_entry, tags, 2 AS relevance FROM blog_posts WHERE MATCH(post_author) AGAINST('%$colname_getPosts%' IN BOOLEAN MODE)".test($colname_getPosts)." 
UNION
SELECT post_id, post_date, post_title, post_author, post_entry, tags, 5 AS relevance FROM blog_posts WHERE MATCH(post_entry) AGAINST('%$colname_getPosts%' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
UNION
SELECT post_id, post_date, post_title, post_author, post_entry, tags, 7 AS relevance FROM blog_posts WHERE MATCH(tags) AGAINST('%$colname_getPosts%' IN BOOLEAN MODE))results
GROUP BY post_id, post_date, post_title, post_author, post_entry, tags ORDER BY relevance DESC";
```

How can I improve it, is their an easier code?

Comment: How can I improve it, is their an easier code that can save time?

Comment: why are you doing everything four times?

Comment: Use sphinx (http://sphinxsearch.com/) or Solr (http://lucene.apache.org/solr/)

Comment: because i have "%'.$arraytags.'" or  %'.$arraytags.'% or '.$arraytags.'% or '.$arraytags.'

Comment: you still only need one loop not 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to have 4 foreach loops and explode the string 4 times since it would be the same array every time.

```
function test($string) {
    $output = '';

    $array = explode(' ', $string);
    foreach ($array as $arraytags) {
        $output .= ' OR MATCH(post_title, post_entry, post_author, tags) AGAINST("%'.$arraytags.'"IN BOOLEAN MODE)';
        $output .= ' OR MATCH(post_title, post_entry, post_author, tags) AGAINST("%'.$arraytags.'%"IN BOOLEAN MODE)';
        $output .= ' OR MATCH(post_title, post_entry, post_author, tags) AGAINST("'.$arraytags.'%"IN BOOLEAN MODE)';
        $output .= ' OR MATCH(post_title, post_entry, post_author, tags) AGAINST("'.$arraytags.'"IN BOOLEAN MODE)';
    }
    return $output;
}
```

This would do the same thing, with out going through the array 4 times more then nessesary.
Your formatting needs some work, it was hard to understand with all the letters bunched up together.